# Traditional HTML/PHP/MySQL vs. modern frameworks

Tags: php, mysql

Back in the late 90s and early 2000s, I used to develop websites in the traditional html/php/mysql. Writing everything by hand with simple text editors like textpad. No dependency on anything else, no 3rd party library or modules. stackoverflow didn't exist back then, my main forum was sitepoint at the time. I didn't jump on the wave of ajax and other php frameworks that used to pop back then. I took a pause from web development since 2008, and some of the sites I developed sadly expired. Now I long to restoring one of them. The new frameworks for developing websites seem complex and heavy-weight. Intimidating even. They may also require a lot of maintenance. I'd like to get your opinions on whether it's worth going through the learning curve of the new frameworks (angular, react, etc.) or just use the good old html/php/mysql skill set I did back in the old days. I still have those skills or can rapidly remember.

Comment: Hi, with respect you should know that Stack Overflow is for solving coding questions, not questions about your personal goals. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Oh ok Bill, thanks, I realize now it's not a specific coding questions. Is there a generic forum/place here where I could ask these kinds of questions.

Comment: Of course you can still write projects in html/php/mysql. That technology stack still works fine. If you want to revive an old project, it's up to you. But the frameworks that have been developed are supposed to make it easy to do things quickly like add a new screen to a website, or develop reusable code functions that are used on multiple screens.

Comment: The invention of the nail gun didn't result in all hammers suddenly no longer working.  You can use any tool you like.

Comment: Frameworks generally give you back what you invest into them. Spend some time learning a full-featured system like [Laravel](https://laravel.com) and you'll have *considerable* tools at your immediate command. Use more lean framework like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) and you can pick and choose what's considered essential. The important principle behind any framework is "can I find a pre-existing solution or is my problem exotic enough I must create my own?" In most cases your problem isn't new, but your business logic is, so focus on that.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's never been easier to develop with straight-up normal HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Browsers are well standardized.  We can do things client-side that were never possible before (such as handling files, editing photos and video, peer-to-peer connectivity, direct cross-domain API access, etc.)

There are many frameworks to choose from, but they're not always necessary.  Many of them are bloated, but some aren't.  Many are bad, but some aren't.  This was the same back in the mid/late 2000s, but now there are an overwhelming number of choices.

Stick to the essentials when possible.  Choose a framework later on if it's the right tool for the job.

Comment: If you're building an *application*, use a framework. If you're building a quick script, use whatever feels best.

Comment: @tadman Nonsense.  There are plenty of straightforward web applications that require no frameworks at all.  Use the tool for the job and don't make generalizations.

Comment: If you're leveraging Composer modules to build an application out of components, sure, but if you're just having at it with bare PHP you're going to end up in rough shape unless you're able to cover off all of the security concerns even the most trivial of applications must address.

Comment: @tadman Or, maybe the web applications I build every day don't even require a server-side backend anymore.  Not every scenario is the same.  Not everyone is making CRUD apps.  Browsers are quite powerful now.

Comment: That's a good point, there are many ways of building "serverless" applications now, but you may want to expand on that particular approach as that's at least two degrees removed from what the person asking the question seems familiar with.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to use good old hand written code, especially if you don't have to rewrite your pages completely. With frameworks/libraries your are a sometimes limited, either in features or in performance. With your own code you can exactly balance your feature and performance needs without an unused code-base. But sometimes it can be useful to use some small libraries to not re-invent the whole wheel.

Comment: This might have been true in 1998 when frameworks were immature and barely better than your own hand-rolled code, but it's absolutely not true now. Out of the box most give you a secure platform for building applications that have protection against major threats like CSRF, XSS and SQL injection, all of which you cannot ignore. Home-rolled code must painfully re-invent the last twenty years of web development. It's just not worth doing except from a purely academic angle.

Comment: Frameworks don't impose limitations per-se, they impose *conventions*, and these conventions help steer your code. You can ignore them and then they feel limiting because they make it harder to do things other than the way they've laid out, but if you follow them they make your life considerably easier. This is all abotu trade-offs. You can have the code work for you, or you can write lots and lots more code to get the same thing done. Not every framework is going to feel right, but the good news is there's many to choose from so don't feel like you're being held prisoner.